# Creating inner ring of polygon using buffered geometry in JTS?

Tags: buffer, jts-topology-suite, self-intersection

I am still a beginner to GIS.

I have a polygon and I want to draw a large border inside the that polygon (see fig A and B below).

With the library I am using, I have to do this with a polygon with "holes" (inner rings).

I use JTS to buffer the polygon with a negative value, which works most of the time.

The issue is that is some situations, the buffered geometry is self intersecting (fig C, red circles) and the rendering library does not like it (not one bit).

How can I go from fig. C to fig. D with JTS ?

[image]

The code is really simple (insetDeg is a negative value) :

> Geometry innerPoly = polygon.buffer(insetDeg);

I then add my innerPoly as an inner ring for the renderer

This is not a code related question, and to me it is more about geometry manipulation know-how.

"Do an intersection of the polygon with itself" is the tip I was looking for.

Comment: Have you tried using a negative buffer distance?  Generally, code is required for coding questions.

Comment: Yes, I am getting at C currently and it works in most situation. I am after the trick to transform C into D for those polygons with "neck".

Comment: Sounds like a library defect to me (which would be off-topic). You still need to [provide code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have provided the relevant code, but I am really doing not much.

Comment: It's not an MCVE unless it can be used to reproduce the issue. You have undefined variables.

Comment: MCVE ? I am unfamiliar with the acronym.